# webpack angularjs routing not working

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-router

Looking for your help 
my app routing not working (its load the home-page) but when i am trying to route to login its not doing anything(like its can't find it, even that i register it)
Couldn't figure this out for a while . Thx for the help!

Here is the files Codes :

Login.index.js :

```
import './login.css'

import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';

import routing from './login.routes';
import LoginController from './login.controller';

export default angular.module('arrowfind.login', [uirouter])
  .config(routing)
  .controller('LoginController', LoginController)
  .name;
```

Login.routes.js :

```
routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      template: require('./login.html'),
      controller: 'LoginController',
      controllerAs: 'login'
    });
}
```

Main App Settings(index.config.js)  :

```
routing.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

export default function routing($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

App Js(index.js) :

```
import './index.css';

import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';

import routing from './index.config';
import navbar from './components/navbar';
import landing from './components/landing';
import login from './components/login';

angular.module('arrowfind', [uirouter, navbar, landing, login])
    .config(routing);
```

The html :

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#/Login" id="loginlink">Login</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly its taken me 8 hours to solve that : 
There was 3 problems :

1) is that I needed to change login to -> Login at Login.Controller.js
2) is that I needed to change #/Login to #!/Login at the HTML
3) is that i needed to remove this $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) at index.config.js;
code because its didn't work with that.

Thx, hope I helped somebody.